# Do the paint() and repaint() methods of java applet and application behave the same way?

Tags: java, applet, paint, repaint

I'm new to java and today I found JFrame also have the method paint and repaint. So my question is does the method paint and repaint behave the same like in java applet? Will the application update itself like applet ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Swing display functionality should behave exactly the same, with respect to behavior of `paint` and `repaint`, when run as an application or as an applet.

More generally, Swing was designed to provide consistent visuals and behavior, regardless of whether the application was running as an application or an applet.